# Make a notification status in android studio

Tags: android, push-notification

is there a way where I can make a simple notification that will check if there is new data coming from the php backend, without the work of gcm / xmpp?

Answer (score 0):

You mingle two things here: Notification and GCM.
Notification is a way to inform the user that something is happening in the app. e.g. a new message was received or a download is happening. 
GCM or FCM is to notifiy the phone from the server about updates etc. Other than on iOS you are not obligated to show a notification upon receiving a push message from GCM.
As to your question, there are two ways to do this:

- Implement your own cloud messaging service (not recommendend because it is a lot effort)
- Using a pull mechanism: Every time your app starts you ask the server for updates. You can do this also periodically while the app runs. The disadvantage of this method is that your app causes traffic and battery every time, even if there are now updates available.

Comment: yeah, but the problem is that it is not availble when the app is in the offline mode. is there a way to do that , to notify the user when it is still in offline mode?

Comment: That is totally different from your initial question. But yes, you can just show a notification, without receiving a push message.